# Calculation is not calculating correctly

Tags: jquery, math, jquery-animate

I want to add or subtract a value to another value. If `a` is `7347.19` and `t` is - and `b` is `1354.34`, count `a` down to `5992.85`. If `t` is + instead, add 50 so the result will be `8701.53`.

`b` will always count down to 0.

The problem is that `$('.counter').text()` will return `7347.19-1354.34` if `t` is minus and `7347.19+1354.34` if `t` is plus. `$('.counter').text()` will also display `NaN` during the countdown.

```
function animate_sum(element, number_, interval_) {
  $({someValue: element.text()}).animate({someValue: number_}, {
    duration: interval_,
    step: function() {
      element.text(Math.floor(this.someValue + 1));
    },
    complete : function() {
      element.text(number_);
    }
  });
}

setTimeout(function() {
  a = $('.counter').text();
  b = $('.counter-difference').text();
  t = $('.counter-difference').attr('data-type');

  animate_sum($('.counter'), (a + t + b), 1000)
  animate_sum($('.counter-difference'), 0, 1000)
}, 1000);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qyaha4r4/)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This operation: `a + t + b` has the following elements:

- `a` is a number
- `t` is a string (its value is `-`)
- `b` is a number

When you use `+` to combine them, Javascript will see that `t` is not a number, but a string, so it will do a **string concatenation** (rather than a mathematical operation). That's why you get `7347.19-1354.34`

To fix this, you need to put an `if` statement to check the value of `t` and decide on what operation you want to do. Something like this:

```
if (t == '+')
    r = a + b;
else
    r = a - b;
```

Comment: Ahaa! Now I understand :) Thanks! But when I changed `t` to a plus sign, the animation for `a` is halted and after the animation for `b` is completed, `a` prints `7347.19100`. Please see the updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qyaha4r4/10/

Comment: @Erik, that happens because `.text()` unsurprisingly returns a `String` rather than `Number` and the crucial difference between `+` and `-` is that `-` is defined only for `Number` so `String`s are first converted into `Number`s but `+` is defined for `String` as concatenation. That's why you got `7347.19100` as a final result. To work this around you might want to force conversion to `Number` for `a` and `b`. One way to do it is to use unary `+` as in `a = + $('.counter').text();` (and similarly for `b`).

Comment: Very true, @SergGr. `r = Number(a) + Number(b);` did the trick! Many thanks!